# Creating AWS IAM Identity Services User but not able to assign permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am not sure if there is a bug in the console right now or if I am misunderstanding things.  I am in my root user account. I followed a guide to create an IAM user for myself and assigned it admin access.  Now I am trying to create another IAM Identity Services user for a coworker with more restricted access. I am able to create a user just fine, but when I go to the "AWS Accounts" tab that new user is not showing up.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot you are in the list AWS Accounts and mentioned that it doesn't show the user and obviously it won't. Did you try to add the user?

Select the account then click on `Add users or groups` > `Select users` > `Assign Permission Set` > `Submit`